# Cast From Arraylist To a String

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, casting

I'm getting one element from the ArrayList using the Random Class. Currently I'm trying to cast this element into a string (unsuccessfully) using ToString. How would i Cast Solutions[r] into a string?

```
ArrayList Solutions = new ArrayList(5);
Solutions.Add("The Odyssey");
Solutions.Add("Dune");
Solutions.Add("Sherlock Holmes");
Solutions.Add("Othello");
Solutions.Add("Of Mice and Men");

Random ran = new Random();
int r = ran.Next(Solutions.Count); 

string s = Solutions[r].ToString;
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` use `List<string>` you don't need to convert it then, as it is already a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = Solutions[r].ToString(); // you're missing brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

using `IList<string>` makes it much more easy and clean.

```
IList<string> Solutions = new List<string>(5);
Solutions.Add("The Odyssey");
Solutions.Add("Dune");
Solutions.Add("Sherlock Holmes");
Solutions.Add("Othello");
Solutions.Add("Of Mice and Men");

Random ran = new Random();
int r = ran.Next(Solutions.Count); 

string s = Solutions[r];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> solutions = new List<String>();

solutions.Add("The Odyssey");
solutions.Add("Dune");
// and so on
```

Then you can:

```
label1 = solution[random_index]; // starts with 0
```